# How to solve combination circuits?

Tags: circuit-analysis, parallel, homework, circuits

We were asked to find the total current and voltage, and also the individual currents and voltages of each resistor.

Please teach me the steps for solving each of the circuits, and if you have any guides or tricks, please share them.

[image: Diagram]

**I tried to calculate the total voltage across the circuit to verify my answer, but I noticed that the sum of the voltages across each individual resistor did not equal the total voltage, some voltage were higher than the source and some were lower. This discrepancy made me think that my answer was incorrect.**

*My Process of simplifying the circuit*
[image]

[image: Table]

To simplify the circuit, I used a series of steps. First, I found the total resistance of parallel resistors R4 and R5. Then, I used this total resistance value to replace R4 and R5 with a single equivalent resistor.

Next, I simplified the circuit by combining R2 and R3 as a series, and R4, R5, and R6 as another series, and replaced each series with a single resistor of their sum.

In the fourth diagram simplification, I added two resistors to form a single equivalent resistor, which can be seen in the fifth diagram simplification. With the total resistance known, I could then solve for the total current using Ohm's law.

Using the equation I = V/R, where I is current, V is voltage, and R is resistance, I multiplied the total current to each resistor in the second diagram simplification and recorded the values in a table.

Overall,  I used several formulas, including the equations for total resistance in a parallel circuit (1/R = 1/R1 + 1/R2 + ... + 1/Rn) and a series circuit (R = R1 + R2 + ... + Rn), to simplify the circuit and solve for the values of the resistors. Although what I didn't get was each voltage of my resistance should sum up into the total voltage and it didn't so I assumed that my answer was wrong

Comment: Please show us what work you have done and where you got stuck. Include this information in the question post, not in a linked document that might not be available for future readers.

Comment: you are half way there ... now calculate the total current and work backwards through the diagrams for voltage and current calculations

Comment: the chart shows a flaw in your knowledge ... the same current does not flow in each of the resistors ... the voltage across each resistor does not add up to the power supply voltage ... that thinking is true only in the 4th diagram with the two resistors

Comment: Learn about Current Dividers and Voltage Dividers and the formulas.

Answer (score 3):

Your chart shows that you found the same current flowing through each resistor. This isn't possible.

For example the current flowing through R1 splits and part of it flows through R2 and R3, and part of it flows through R4, R5, and R6. So the current through R2 and R3 must be less than the current through R1. The current through the R2-R3 branch must sum up with the current through the R4/R5-R6 branch to make the current through R1.

When the current splits, you can use the current divider rule (for example on your 3rd diagram) to determine how much flows through each branch.